# mysql SUM of VARCHAR fields without using CAST

Tags: mysql

When SUM is used in query on field of type VARCHAR in MySql database, does SUM automatically convert it into number ?
I tried this by using

```
  SELECT SUM(parametervalue) FROM table
```

and it reveals that MySql returns the sum although I expected to throw it an error as "parametervalue" field is of VARCHAR type

Comment: See [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/type-conversion.html).

Comment: It's not really the `SUM` aggregate that's doing the conversion; MySQL  **implicitly converts** the expression to **numeric** when the expression is evaluated in a numeric context. (In this case, the expression is a simple reference to a VARCHAR column, and the `SUM()` aggregate is a numeric context. This doesn't happen with just the `SUM()` aggregate, the implicit conversion happens _anywhere_ a VARCHAR expression is encountered in a numeric context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MySQL does silent conversion for a string in a numeric context.  Because it expects a number for the `sum()`, MySQL simply does the conversion using the leading "numbers" from a string.  Note that this include decimal points, minus sign, and even `e` representing scientific notation.  So, `'1e6'` is interpreted as a number.

In code, I personally would make the conversion explicit by adding `0`:

```
SELECT SUM(parametervalue + 0) FROM table
```

Ironically, the `cast()` might return an error if the string is not in a numeric format, but this doesn't return an error in that case.

Comment: "*this doesn't return an error in that case*" - doesn't that depend on SQL mode?

Comment: @eggyal . . . There probably is a mode that changes this behavior.