# MySQL - what does SUM(string value) actually do?

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm trying to figure out how MySQL treats strings in a SUM() function. Granted, this likely won't happen on purpose, but I've had students ask me what MySQL is doing and why it's providing a valid answer (although it may not make any sense) instead of an error.

For example, here is some sample data:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (my_string VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('1 thing'),
('2 things'),
('three things'),
('4 things'),
('five things'),
('six things');
```

The query

```
SELECT SUM(my_string) FROM my_table;
```

yields

```
+----------------+
| SUM(my_string) |
+----------------+
|              7 |
+----------------+
```

I can't find anything in the reference manual that discusses this.

Anybody have an idea of why this query produces these results and not an error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ... and will result in an error in essentially every other database (allowing this is simply stupid in my opinion)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql SUM of VARCHAR fields without using CAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812324/mysql-sum-of-varchar-fields-without-using-cast)

Comment: ? But you can see what it's doing.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for - thank you! The referenced question is too abstract for the audience who needs to see this answer (it's not just for me, it's also to help students with little to no SQL experience).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question could be considered a duplicate of [mysql SUM of VARCHAR fields without using CAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812324/mysql-sum-of-varchar-fields-without-using-cast)

Specifically, the string '10% Happier' is being translated to 10, and every other string to 0, so the `sum()` or total is 10.

EDIT to follow the question's edit:

```
('1 thing'), becomes 1
('2 things'), becomes 2
('three things'), becomes 0
('4 things'), becomes 4
('five things'), becomes 0
('six things'); becomes 0
```

1+2+0+4+0+0 = 7.

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much!! Guess it was rocket science afterall...